# Export type declaration outside of the function

Tags: google-closure-compiler, typechecking

I'm trying to use google closure compiler (I'll call it `compiler` for short) to *validate* JavaScript codebase like that:

`java -jar compiler.jar --js='**.js' --jscomp_error newCheckTypes > NUL 2> gcc.log`

The thing is we already have a lot of code in AMD and type annotations written for core modules like that:

```
define(function () {
    /** @constructor */
    MyClass () {}
    /** @param {string} s */
    MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function (s) {
        alert(s);
    }
    return MyClass;
});
```

I'd like to reference the type `/** @type {MyClass} */` in other modules, so if I call some method with wrong arguments, it will complaint.

Unfortunately, when I use such type annotations, `compiler` outputs:

```
Bad type annotation. Unknown type MyClass
    /** @type {MyClass} */
```

If I strip out module-delcaring function, `compiler` "understands" my declaration, but I don't feel like rewriting our code in that way.

Is there a way to make `compiler` see my type declarations and apply in other modules?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler has a `--transform_amd_modules` which will rewrite an AMD module to CommonJS. It only supports a limited number of `define` signatures and is not widely used or actively maintained.

With CommonJS modules, you can use the `--process_common_js_modules` flag to rewrite and rescope the code to a global type which can be checked by the compiler. The CommonJS modules functionality is actively maintained.

Comment: So you're suggesting transform modules to CommonJS and then call compiler again providing transformed code?

Comment: No - it would all be done internally to the compiler in a run. Just provide both the `--transform_amd_modules` and `--process_common_js_modules` flags.

Comment: I didn't expect it to work correctly aaand... it hasn't worked.
I still see all those errors. Have I explained clearly that I don't need to transform code in any way - only validate types like with flowtype.

Comment: @kirilloid The transformations are simply so the compiler can correctly understand the types. I have my doubts that it's good enough to support your use case though - mainly because of the limited signatures that are supported for `define`. If you post a sample of the errors you see, I'll take a look. I'm not aware of any other way to handle this, unless you used a preprocessing tool to rewrite the modules for you.